# CRM Import fails with "Fields that are not valid were specified for the entity"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

When importing a solution to CRM 2011 I get the following error message:

> Fields that are not valid were specified for the entity

This message is seen when importing into an environment where a previous version of the solution exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be observed in the following scenario (where the environments are called "Dev" and "Test"):

1. A field is added to Dev and imported into Test.
2. The field is deleted from Dev.
3. A new field with the same name but a different type is added to Dev.
4. The solution is imported into Test and fails with the above message.

Manually delete the field(s) in Test before importing the solution to resolve the problem.

Comment: How do we figure out which fields it's talking about?

Comment: @pabrams Probably too late to help you but I just encountered this. Click the Download Log File button and open with Excel. There is a tab labelled components. Scroll through the ErrorText column to see the offending column